# How can I create an optional DateTime parameter?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, reference-type

I have this function that returns a reference type. Now, this function has two optional parameters both of which are instances of the `DateTime` class. The function is something like this:

```
public DateTime GetDate(DateTime start = DateTime.MinValue, DateTime end = DateTime.MinValue)
{
    // Method body...
}
```

The error from VS is:

> Default parameter value for 'start' must be a compile-time constant

Of course, the error applies to the second parameter and I perfectly understand what is happening.

What I really want is to know if there is a way to go about this, that is, having optional parameters in the method. Right now, what I have done is to create an overload; I mean, I have created a parameterless function `GetDate()` and a two-parameter overload of it.

This is not really a problem but I just want to know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type and not a reference type.

Comment: I know, which is the purpose of my question.

Comment: Your question seems to be how to specify two DateTime parameters as optional. There's no reference types at all involved in this question.

Comment: I thought the title was explicit enough.

Comment: Yes, but there are still no reference types in play here. None.

Comment: Okay, I get you. Do you think I should include a reference to `reference` in the question?

Comment: I don't see why. This question is about optional parameters of type `DateTime`.

Comment: Well, I believe it applies to any reference type as well. Originally I never meant to mention the actual type in the question. I thought of it later. The same error would have appeared if I had used any other reference type.

Comment: Do what you want, but mislabelling questions will not get you the correct eyeballs on it. If you want people to look at your question because they might have experience with it, you should try to label the question correctly according to what you ask. In this case there is no reference types involved, and the question, as you point out, would not change if you had involved the actual types which you say are reference types, so in reality the question is not about reference types. It's about optional parameters where there is no easy way to specify a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One workaround is to assign them like this:

```
public DateTime GetDate(DateTime? start = null, DateTime? end = null){
    start = start ?? DateTime.MinValue;
    end = end ?? DateTime.MinValue;

    Console.WriteLine ("start: " + start);
    Console.WriteLine ("end: " + end);
    return DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
void Main()
{
    new Test().GetDate();
    new Test().GetDate(start: DateTime.UtcNow);
    new Test().GetDate(end: DateTime.UtcNow);
    new Test().GetDate(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

And works just as expected:

```
start: 1/01/0001 0:00:00
end: 1/01/0001 0:00:00

start: 8/08/2014 17:30:29
end: 1/01/0001 0:00:00

start: 1/01/0001 0:00:00
end: 8/08/2014 17:30:29

start: 8/08/2014 17:30:29
end: 8/08/2014 17:30:29
```

Note the named parameter to distinguish between the `start` and `end` value.

Comment: I actually thought of using `nullable`s but I was wondering how I was going to pass it to the function. I was about to make a comment about that when your answer came through.

Comment: A `Nullable<T>` can always get `T` assigned to it, you don't have to explicitly make a conversion happen.

Answer (score 11):

Btw, you don't have to use nullable datetime like all other answers says. You can do it with `DateTime` as well:

```
public DateTime GetDate(
     DateTime start = default(DateTime), 
     DateTime end = default(DateTime))
{
     start = start == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.MinValue : start;
     end = end == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.MinValue : end;
}
```

This is unlikely but it won't work as expected if you actually pass the default datetime value to your function.

Comment: Hmmm... So what is the value of `default(DateTime)` that I shouldn't pass?

Comment: it is equal to `new DateTime()`

Comment: default(DateTime) = new DateTime() = DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 5):

The only way would be to do it like this (a bit more code, but it gives you optional args):

```
public DateTime GetDate(DateTime? start = null, DateTime? end = null)
{
    // Method body...
    if(start == null)
    {
      start = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    //same for end
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `DateTime` to be nullable and then convert to `DateTime.Min` if no parameter is provided:

```
public DateTime GetDate(DateTime? start = null, DateTime? end = null) {
    var actualStart = start ?? DateTime.Min;
    var actualEnd = end ?? DateTime.Min;
}
```