# Set default datetime parameter in function to use current year

Tags: c#

I'm coding functions that determine whether a given date is in the previous/same/next year, and these functions might have a different "start of year" date (financial years, chinese new years etc.).

Given that the code (as an example) reads:

```
public static class ValidationFunctions
{
...
    public static bool IsPreviousYear(DateTime value)
    {
        DateTime defaultStartOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
        return IsPreviousYear(value, defaultStartOfYear);
    }
...
    public static bool IsPreviousYear(DateTime value, DateTime startOfYear)
    {
        return value >= startOfYear.AddYears(-1) && value < startOfYear;
    }
...
}
```

How do I change this function (or what, where and how do I add to the class), to perform the equivalent of:

```
public static class ValidationFunctions
{
...
    public static bool IsPreviousYear(DateTime value)
    {
        DateTime defaultStartOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
        return IsPreviousYear(value, defaultStartOfYear);
    }
...
    public static bool IsPreviousYear(DateTime value, DateTime startOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 5))
    {
        return value >= startOfYear.AddYears(-1) && value < startOfYear;
    }
...
}
```

I understand that the above code throws an ArgumentException and ArgumentOutOfRangeException (mostly due to the `DateTime.Now.Year` component), hence the question.  I've read similar questions that provide the current date, but I just need the year; the similar questions also don't explicitly cover my requirement, or don't seem to at any rate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [optional parameters of reference types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208969/optional-parameters-of-reference-types)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: You could just copy paste your answer :) +1

Comment: @JeroenVannevel thanks for directing me to the answer, apologies for not knowing that was what I should look for.

Comment: @DavidSmithson: can't really blame you since that other question had such a bad title. I've changed it so it's more clear now.

Comment: By the way, based on the Microsoft Design rules using optional parameters is a bad practice and they should be replaced with overloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until this gets closed off as a duplicate question, I'll post the question it duplicates as an answer (I don't like having unanswered questions on my account):

[How can I create an optional DateTime parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208969/how-can-i-create-an-optional-datetime-parameter)

Comment: But if it's a duplicate question (and there's even an answer to your question in the duplicate) then why don't you delete your post or mark it as duplicate yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You use a nullable parameter and give it a default value of `null`:

```
public static bool IsPreviousYear(DateTime value, DateTime? startOfYear = null)
{
    startOfYear = startOfYear ?? new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 5);
    return value >= startOfYear.Value.AddYears(-1) && value < startOfYear.Value;
}
```

Default values for parameters have to be constant, and there is no way to specify a constant `DateTime` value, so the only value left that is possible is to use `null` with a nullable `DateTime`.

Even if it was possible to specify a default value for a `DateTime` parameter, other than `null` for a nullable `DateTime`, you would still have to specify a constant value, so you would not be able to handle the "current year" part of it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the default values are substitued at compile-time by the C# compiler; *not* at runtime by the JIT or CLR.

Hence it's impossible to have a dynamic optional parameter (e.g. based on current year).